# Summarise node table

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I've got a table such as below :

```
x <- data.frame(
  old = c("start1", "start2", "start3", "start4", "inter1", "inter2", "inter3"),
  new = c("final1", "final1", "inter1", "inter3", "inter2", "final2", "final3")
)

    old    new
 start1 final1
 start2 final1
 start3 inter1
 start4 inter3
 inter1 inter2
 inter2 final2
 inter3 final3
```

I would like to have directly the "final node" for each line.
On the example above it would be :

```
res <- data.frame(
  old= c("start1", "start2", "start3", "start4", "inter1", "inter2", "inter3"),
  new = c("final1", "final1", "final2", "final3", "final3", "final2", "final3")
)

    old    new
 start1 final1
 start2 final1
 start3 final2
 start4 final3
 inter1 final3
 inter2 final2
 inter3 final3
```

I guess something recursive must be done (knowing there can be multiple level) but I can't go through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a loop here

```
while(length(toupdate <- which(x$new %in% x$old))>0) {
  x$new[toupdate] <- x$new[match(x$new[toupdate], x$old)]
}
x
#      old    new
# 1 start1 final1
# 2 start2 final1
# 3 start3 final2
# 4 start4 final3
# 5 inter1 final2
# 6 inter2 final2
# 7 inter3 final3
```

Here we iterate while any of the "new" values are in the "old" column. We find them, then use `match` to look up what the "new" value is each each of those intermediate values. We loop until there are no more to update.

And if you are using graph-like data, the `igraph` library can be helpful. Here's how you might use it in this case

```
gg <- graph_from_data_frame(x)
plot(gg)

lapply(decompose(gg), function(sg) {
  av <- adjacent_vertices(sg, V(sg), "out")
  cbind(V(sg)$name[lengths(av)!=0], names(av[lengths(av)==0]))
}) |> do.call("rbind", args=_) |> data.frame()

#       X1     X2
# 1 start1 final1
# 2 start2 final1
# 3 start3 final2
# 4 inter1 final2
# 5 inter2 final2
# 6 start4 final3
# 7 inter3 final3
```

It works by treating the input as a directed graph. We then decompose it into non-overlapping parts and for each part, we find the node that has no out-going connections.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use `igraph`, you can try `subcomponent` like below (but this might be not ***inefficient*** due to rowwise operations, e.g., `sapply`)

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(x)
x %>%
  mutate(new = sapply(
    old,
    function(v) tail(names(subcomponent(g, v, "out")), 1)
  ))
```

which gives

```
     old    new
1 start1 final1
2 start2 final1
3 start3 final2
4 start4 final3
5 inter1 final2
6 inter2 final2
7 inter3 final3
```

---

Probably a more ***efficient*** way is using `membership` + `left_join`

```
x %>%
  left_join(
    {.} %>%
      graph_from_data_frame() %>%
      components() %>%
      membership() %>%
      enframe(),
    by = join_by(old == name)
  ) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(new = grep("^final", new, value = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-value)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  old    new
  <chr>  <chr>
1 start1 final1
2 start2 final1
3 start3 final2
4 start4 final3
5 inter1 final2
6 inter2 final2
7 inter3 final3
```